# Discord API 401: Unauthorized error

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to get audit logs from my server using discord API. I'm sending my authorization token in headers but it's still returning error 401.

**My code:**

```
headers = {
    'authorization': AUTH_TOKEN        
}

params = {
    'limit':'50',
    'user_id': USER_ID,
    'action_type': '40',
    'authorization': AUTH_TOKEN
}

r = requests.get(f'https://discordapp.com/api/v6/guilds/{SERVER_ID}/audit-logs', params=params)
```

**Output:**

```
{"code": 0, "message": "401: Unauthorized"}
```

I tried sending user-agent and stuff like that in headers but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: did you try to change the `authorization` to `Authorization`

Comment: Yes lol. I tried that and it didn't work. Anyway, I solved it by using my bot's token. THANKS

Comment: @Bharat Thank you so much for posting your solution!

Answer (score 16):

If you're using a bot, you must prefix your Authorization header token with 'Bot'

i.e.

```
headers = {
    'authorization' : 'Bot asdhgaisudg7asd',
}
```

See https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/602

Comment: what if you are not using a bot? i get the same error trying to use a user token

Comment: For a user token, try following [these instructions](https://discordjs.guide/oauth2/#getting-an-oauth2-url)