# 401 Unauthorized error while trying send message as a user to Discord via API

Tags: discord

I'm trying to reach Discord via rest api, however POST [https://discord.com/api/v8/channels/{some_channel_id}/messages](https://discord.com/api/v8/channels/%7Bsome_channel_id%7D/messages)
doesn't work, i also added Authorization header, with "Bearer token".
Response is always the same, 401: Unauthorized

Comment: are u implementing a bot?
maybe take a look at this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61442389/10028925)

Comment: @MarkusGumpoltsberger i had tried as a Bot and as Bearer with different token, but got same error